Is the sum of fermionic creation and annihilation operator a unitary operator?
$$(c + c^\dagger) (c+ c^\dagger)= c^2 +c^{\dagger 2}+ c c^\dagger + c^\dagger c= I$$ by using the standard anticommutation relations. Is this correct? If this is true, how to achieve this unitary operation $(c+ c^\dagger)$ in a fermionic system as a unitary gate in a quantum computer or quantum simulator?

$\uparrow$ Yes.

@Qmechanic Thanks. Do you know how to physically perform this unitary operation on a fermionic system?

What do you mean with "achieve this unitary operation in a fermionic system"?

@TobiasFünke like we perform a unitary gate in a quantum computer or any Hamiltonian evolution.

Particle-number conservation would usually prevent any physical implementation --- except in a superconductor.

@mikestone: nah, I see only one fermion component.  The number-non-conserving terms just die, and it's just the identity operator.  You implement it by... doing nothing?

@Vokaylop  I imagine (I can't read his mind of course) that operation that the OP wants to implement is the $a^\dagger +a$. The $I$ is there becuase the OP wants to  verify unitarity.

@mikestone ah I see.  But that term is single-electron and SC still doesn't help.  It just describes normal electron tunneling to and from somewhere else, right?

@Vokaylop. In a triplet BCS phase  such as $^3$He-A, $a+a^\dagger$ might create a quasiparticle.

For what it's worth, if we consider the CAR algebra
$$\{c,c\}_+~=~0, \qquad \{c,c^{\dagger}\}_+~=~I, \qquad \{c^{\dagger},c^{\dagger}\}_+~=~0,  \tag{1}$$
and the fermionic Fock space $${\cal H}~=~\mathbb{C}|0\rangle+\mathbb{C}|1\rangle, \qquad |1\rangle~=~c^{\dagger}|0\rangle,\qquad c|0\rangle~=~0, \tag{2}$$
then OP's operator
$$U~=~c+c^{\dagger}~=~|0\rangle\langle 1|+|1\rangle\langle 0|\tag{3}$$
is a self-adjoint involution.
